# shared_ptr/unique_ptr in a multi processor, shared memory environment

Tags: c++, embedded

I'm working on a multi processor SoC.  There are several processors (asymmetric multiprocessing), all that share access to the main memory pool but with some local memory other processors can't see.    The shared memory is all accessible by the same address on all processors.

We want to use reference counted buffers, etc. to better control the lifetime of buffers (there's a lot of passing of buffers along processing chains and across processor boundaries) but we need the thread safety mechanism to be more than thread safe; it needs to be processor safe.

Is there a mechanism to provide std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr new 'atomizing' methods that would allow me to cross the processor boundary?  Or am I looking at rolling my own?  (which I might have to do anyways, depending on what 'hidden' allocations happen in the std versions.

Comment: You need to check your specific implementation's technical documentation. Nothing like this is in the scope of the C++ standard, but your specific C++ implementation is likely to provide some kind of platform-specific features for this.

Comment: By itself `std::shared_ptr` isn't even fully atomic within one process. In C++20 you get `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>>` to solve that problem, but it's only atomic within a single process.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  yeah, I was just hoping there was a way to provide the atomizing mechanism similar to the way some std classes offer for their allocators.  Oh well.